# BackupPC: SMB share backup does not back up OneDrive folders inside the SMB share

Tags: server, permissions, samba, backup, backuppc

Pretty new to Ubuntu as I built a small server/NAS to back up my photos to.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on the server and created a 3 disk Raid Z1 pool as my backup volume.

I set up BackupPC to backup my entire Windows user folder using SMB share.

Many of my folders inside my user folder, indluding Documents and Pictures, are also being synchronised to OneDrive for my off-site storage.

The backup process works but all the folders associated with OneDrive are not containing any files in the backup. OneDrive is set up to keep all files available offline on my PC and I have checked with the command prompt that I can get to them and that they are inside the drive and share.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Thanks, as I understand it this would essentially run OneDrive on Ubuntu and mirror a copy of my OneDrive files on the Ubuntu machine?

There are some non-OneDrive folders I would like to incorporate in the backup too, but I suppose I could back them up separately.

Using OneDrive to mirror my files to my Ubuntu machine however wouldn't provide incremental backups and snapshots? As in, if the files on OneDrive get corrupted they'd be corrupted on my Ubuntu mirror too?

Comment: Not used it myself but my impression is the reverse... files on Ubuntu will be synced with OneDrive or rather mirrored so that a change on one is reflected in the other. That's the way it works with Dropbox. Save a file directly to Db and it will appear in the synced directory on Ubuntu or save a file to the synced Db folder on Ubuntu and it will appear on Db.

Comment: As the developer / maintainer for the OneDrive Client for Linux (https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive) - the github gist referenced above is not correct.

What you need to do is the following:
* Configure the 'sync_dir' option of the OneDrive client to use the SMB folder share you are backing up to
* Configure the client so that you are performing only an upload sync, with no remote delete
* Test your configuration before making it active

Have questions - ask on the client discussion board on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Read this article for possible reasons. https://www.bruceb.com/2019/08/your-backup-program-is-not-backing-up-onedrive-files-but-its-okay/

TL:DR; Most backup software now completely ignores anything in folders containing "onedrive" in their name.

Also make sure the "File on demand" feature of onedrive is disabled. This will make it look like the files are there, but in reality they are not.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this article (and it's quite funny considering the OHV data center in Strasbourg burning down with backups being in the same site). File on demand is switched off, everything is present on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried adding the missing folders in their own SMB share. Windows responds that the sharing of these folders is not possible, so I must come to the conclusion that SMB share backups for files associated with OneDrive is not possible.

Looks like I will need to look into rsync. *despairs*